# Error while running shell script in Jenkin pipeline

Tags: angular, shell, jenkins, groovy, build

I need to remove all files from directory except name matching one defined in variable.

```
                stage ('build'){
                        sh "npm run build"
                        sh 'rm -v !(''''dist/folder1/file.''' + name+ '''.json'''')'
                    }
```

first line create a build for angular project and it has dist folder where I need to remove files in folder1.

Error is below

Syntax error: "(" unexpected with rm exclude file command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error details and alternative solutions you can in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file/153863#153863). Try code below:

```
sh "find . ! -name 'file.${name}.json' -type f -exec rm -f {} +"
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives same error. script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Try with escape characters for `()`

Comment: I can't use with escape char () because without this it consider ! char as part of directory for ex.   sh "rm -v !dist/folder1/file.${name}.json"

Comment: after using escape char it is giving below error in jenkins pipeline WorkflowScript: 102: unexpected char: '\'

Comment: Thanks Sers, it is working fine. Thanks for your help. I am accepting your answer.